# SonarQube 6.1 not calculating lines of code after upgrade and database migration

Tags: mysql, .net, postgresql, sonarqube

tl;dr: SonarQube calculates lines of code metric for some projects but not others after an upgrade.

Hello everyone,
I recently took over an orphaned SonarQube 5.1 installation running on MySQL 5.1 on another server. When I upgraded SQ to 5.6.2 it told me that it required MySQL 5.6. Because the servers in question are CentOS 7 that version of MySQL is not available through yum. Use of yum is required for installing software. I installed PostgreSQL on the SQ server and, because I did not want to lose SQ history and configuration, migrated the database from MySQL to Postgres using [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/) (see pgloader.conf in code block below). The migration appeared to have worked as the schema changes 5.1->5.6.2 succeeded as did 5.6.2->6.1.

```
LOAD DATABASE
   FROM mysql://USER:PASSWORD@mysqlhost.my.com/sonar
   INTO postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@pghost.my.com/sonar
with create indexes, preserve index names;
```

However, some projects that existed before the upgrade and migration and also some projects that have been added (through Jenkins) after the migration never have the Lines of Code metric calculated. These are primarily but not exclusively C# files.

I don't see any way to "reset" a project in the UI or web API. If I could export the SQ configuration, I would wipe the database and reload, but I don't see a way to do that either. Starting from scratch is undesirable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have given up and dropped the database to start over.